# Java Spring MVC 404 not found

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have these 2 methods

```
@RequestMapping(value="/")
public ModelAndView listContact(ModelAndView model) throws IOException{
    List<Contact> listContact = contactDAO.list();
    model.addObject("listContact", listContact);
    model.setViewName("home");
    return model;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/newContact", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView newContact(ModelAndView model) {
    Contact newContact = new Contact();
    model.addObject("contact", newContact);
    model.setViewName("ContactForm");
    return model;
}
```

I Also have the required Views called: home.jsp & ContactForm.jsp (in WEB-INF folder)

The home one works, the ContactForm keeps giving me 404.. please help!

Edit:

I followed this tutorial http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-with-jdbctemplate-example (copied it to be exact, to rule out typos)

I'd like to mention that i do not have a spring-servlet.xml or an applicationContext.xml file, nor did he have that in the tutorial, but something makes me feel like i need it XD

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please share 404 message.

Comment: No further message, 404 not found.

Comment: @Kasper Sølvstrøm could it be case sensitive issue, just a doubt, check for spell `ContactForm`

Comment: Spelled correctly. and is it correct to assune that it should say /newContact in the Url, and then land on view ContactForm ?

Comment: The 404 error: description: The requested resource is not available.

Comment: How are you calling `/newContent`? Is it definitely a GET request?

Comment: <h3><a href="newContact">New Contact</a></h3> that is my link

Comment: Anyone? i need help badly! xD